# Find out issues about miswritten variables or any other bug, in php?

Tags: php, compiler-errors

I had a code where a variable was written with "D" instead of "d", and it took me some time to figure out the code was not the problem, but how the variable was written.  For example here : I had to use `echo 'aa';` to find the wrong line :

```
$lastday = clone $firstDay;
$lastday->modify("last day of this month");
$offsetInit = $firstDay->format("w");
$offsetEnd = 6 - $lastday->format("w");
$firstDay->modify("-$offsetInit days" );
echo "aa";
$lastDay->modify("+$offsetEnd days"); //Day instead of day
echo " bb";
$initWeek = clone $firstDay;
$endWeek = clone $firstDay;
$endWeek->modify("+7 days");
```

Is there a way, a tool on Chrome or anything like this, to figure out were the issue can come from. I am using Netbeans and the variable was not highlighted.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, there is a tool: _read the http servers error log file where php tells you exactly what you ask about._

Comment: And a side note: php names are case sensitive. So your statement "the code was not the problem, but how the variable was written" is not really true. `$lastday` and `$lastDay` are simply two different variables. Your code caused the error at runtime.

Comment: @arkascha so, can you be a bit more precise about where to find the http sever log file? I am using MAMP and Chrome. As for the 2/ I am sure you understood what I said.

Comment: Assuming that you are using php inside an http server environment (as opposed to CLI usage) the error log file is configured inside the host configuration of your http server. Typically it will be somewhere like `/var/log/apache2/... but your configuration may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an [IDE like PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) (or the free [community edition](http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/Download)). It will highlight common coding errors for you (e.g. unused variables will be highlighted etc.) which can help you spot these things. It will also autocomplete variable names, function names, etc. to reduce the chance of you making these errors in the first place.